# Restrict access to fields if not authorized in REST-ful API

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Let say you have a `User` resource. It has many fields. However, not all fields should be allowed to updated by a regular user, but admins should be allowed. Are there any common solutions to this?

E.g. `enabled` should only be allowed to be updated by using a `PUT` request  if the authorized user is an admin. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of spring-security authorization? They have a way of hiding the fields based on the user roles. If your app is large, it makes sense to integrate this.

1. Lookup for methodlevel security
2. Domain object security (ACL)

Answer (score 0):

Good article about entity filtering here 
    http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/02/04/filtering-jax-rs-entities-with-standard-security-annotations/